# How do I get the Info window's log text with Python?

Tags: python, add-on, panel

I'm creating a Blender addon, however, I do not know how to access the 'INFO' (The window you drag from the top) windows log text.

If I could access that, I could create logs and such.
I've tried lots of things, however, I couldn't crack it. Is there any way to get the text of the 'INFO' window?

If you need more information, just ask.

Comment: Just throwing this out...you can press "A" to select all, then copy/paste. (I know this is a lot more engaging actually putting it into practice, but I don't have time to do so right now)

Comment: Run `bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()`  from the console. Creates a text block "Recent Reports".

Comment: @batFinger You should make that an answer. @everyone I will add that you can get a string of text by using `bpy.data.texts["Recent Reports"].as_string` provided that there is only one text block named "Recent Reports" (to avoid "Recent Reports.001" auto-numbering problems)

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes batFinger please make that answer, along with pycoders adjustment ;)

Comment: Do you know how to overwrite the file instead of creating new ones like Recent Reports.001 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Reports to text block operator [`bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.ui.html?highlight=reports_to_textblock#bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock) .**

The operator [`bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.ui.html?highlight=reports_to_textblock#bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock)  lists reports from the info area

[image]

into a text block named "Recent Reports"([.nnn] if run more than once.)

[image]

Test code. Removes existing recent reports before running operator.

```
#remove other Recent Reports
reports = [bpy.data.texts.remove(t, do_unlink=True) 
           for t in bpy.data.texts
           if t.name.startswith("Recent Reports")]
# make a report
bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()
# print the report
for line in bpy.data.texts["Recent Reports"].lines:
    # if line.body.startswith("Operator:"): #it's an operator
    print(line.body)
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Blender version 2.81, `bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock` was removed, (see [D5510](https://developer.blender.org/D5510)) because the functionality to *read* Info was already available through the [`bpy.ops.info`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.info.html) operators.

While copying to and from the clipboard is perhaps less straightforward, the developers recommended that something like the following *pseudocode* be used

```
bpy.ops.info.select_all()
bpy.ops.info.report_copy()
```

to copy the report selection to the clipboard, and then the [text](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.text.htmlhttps://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.text.html) operator `bpy.ops.text.paste()` be used to read from the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for updating this thread with newer information!