# Get Info Editor logs with Python API

Tags: python, scripting

I want to get the log of the last used commands from the Info window, or anywhere else, if there's another way.

I found this answer [How do I get the Info window's log text with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62360/how-do-i-get-the-info-windows-log-text-with-python), but apparently Blender's current version doesn't have `bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()` anymore, so I'm kind of lost now.

Comment: I've just added [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62360/how-do-i-get-the-info-windows-log-text-with-python/240865#240865) to that question which shows how to do it in later versions of blender.  Is that what you're looking for?