# How to access the Context Menu Info?

Tags: python

I want to access these commands through code and add them in the array

it helps me to make a tool like photoshop actions

[image]

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'OBJECT'
bpy.context.object.location[0] = 5
bpy.context.object.location[1] = 10
bpy.context.object.location[2] = 15
bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[0] = 0.523599
bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[1] = 1.22173
bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2] = 0.349066
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Copy and Paste.**

Previously available via `bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()`

[How to read all ‘recent reports’ from info window](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147692/how-to-read-all-recent-reports-from-info-window)

[How do I get the Info window's log text with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62360/how-do-i-get-the-info-windows-log-text-with-python)

The operator appears unavailable in 2.8, however it is a simple matter of selecting and copying from the info area

Silly test script, toggles into the info area, selects all, copies, toggles back to text area and pastes.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

# change to info
context.area.type = 'INFO'
bpy.ops.info.select_all()
bpy.ops.info.report_copy()
context.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
bpy.ops.text.paste() # silly
```

The clipboard contents

```
>>> for line in C.window_manager.clipboard.splitlines():
...     line
...     
"bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'INFO'"
"bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'"
'bpy.ops.text.run_script()'
'Python script failed, check the message in the system console'
"bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'"
"bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'INFO'"
"bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'"
'bpy.ops.text.run_script()'
```

See the docs for info area space on toggling info report types.  `a` is an 'INFO' type area

```
>>> a.type
'INFO'

>>> a.spaces.active.show_
                         locked_time
                         region_header
                         report_debug
                         report_error
                         report_info
                         report_operator
                         report_warning
```

Comment: oh, it isn't a silly way! it's a clever way!  I could access the clipboard by this line of code  ```clipboard = bpy.context.window_manager.clipboard```

Comment: silly in that was pasting back into itself..